# What are null certificates in Gnome Seahorse?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, certificate

In the "Default Trust" tab in [Seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Seahorse?action=show&redirect=Seahorse) there are several personal certificates named simply "(null)", which are issued by "No name". There's nothing on their property pages. What are these? Can they be safely deleted?

[image: Screenshot of Seahorse]

I [run GNOME Keyring Daemon](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/eba6a3e515ba25595253093da13894a2e37a506e/.xprofile#L37-L38) like this:

```
eval $(/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=gpg,pkcs11,secrets,ssh)
export GPG_AGENT_INFO SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Comment: This is a Linux-specific question. Voting to migrate. BTW - it's GNOME Keyring that's at issue, not the Seahorse UI.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @sebix Not sure what good it'll do, but here you go.

Comment: I do not have these. Which OS do you use?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe better ask the manjaro devs: https://forum.manjaro.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are seeing are *anonymous certificates*.

I have never had reason to use such certificates, but apparently
you can get them, for example, at the
[Anonymous Web Hosting website](https://www.anonymousspeech.com/anonymous_hosting_ssl.aspx),
where you can find in the FAQ :

> **A:** Is this a shared SSL Certificate with a shared IP address?
> **Q:** No, this is your private SSL certificate. If you are on a shared hosting contract, we will give you a dedicated IP address for free.
>
> **Q:**  Do I need to provide my private address in order to get an SSL certificate ?
> **A:** No, **the certificate is does not need a correct address or name in order to be approved**. Only an easy email confirmation is needed. SSL certificates with address confirmation are more expensive and do not make sense if you want to be anonymous.

[RFC 3647](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3647.txt) of the IETF,
which defines the
Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure
Certificate Policy and Certification Practices Framework,
also describes the existence of such certificates:

> In general, a public-key certificate (hereinafter "certificate") binds
> a public key held by an entity (such as person, organization, account,
> device, or site) to a set of information that identifies the entity
> associated with use of the corresponding private key.  In most cases
> involving identity certificates, this entity is known as the "subject"
> or "subscriber" of the certificate.  Two exceptions, however, include
> devices (in which the subscriber is usually the individual or
> organization controlling the device) and
> **anonymous certificates (in which the identity of the individual or organization is not available from the certificate itself).**

I can only guess that they were installed by some software on your computer
for its own private purposes, perhaps for a local Web proxy that does HTTPS.

In any case, I wouldn't delete them, since that might render unusable
the software that installed them.